# comparing a map and List and extracting element from List

Tags: java, collections

I have a Map and a List My list a master list of some value object and Map contains keys which are id of the value object
 I have a value object

```
 public class Value
{


    private int id;

    private String value;

//set and gets to follow
}

Map valueMap = new HashMap();   

valueMap.put(1001,"Test1")//key is id of the value object 
valueMap.put(1002,"Test2")
valueMap.put(1003,"Test3")


 List list = new Array list();
 list.add(value1)
 list.add(value2)
 list.add(value3)
 list.add(value4)
 list.add(value5)
```

From the list i want to extract  a subset of list whose value.id is ==key of map

how can i do and iterate over both?

Comment: Iterate over the `List` and ask for each if the *id* exists as a key in the `Map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

```
Map<Integer, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
List<Value> subset = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<Value> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Value val = iterator.next();
    if (valueMap.containsKey(val.getId())) {
        subset.add(val);
    }
}
```

or even

```
List<Value> subset = new ArrayList<>();
for (Value val : list) {
    if (valueMap.containsKey(val.getId())) {
        subset.add(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of class value you can just use the provided class Map.Entry

anyway you can iterate over the list and extract the values from the map:

```
for ( Value v : list ) {
    int id = v.getID();
    value = valueMap.get(id);

    if ( value != null ) {
        doSomething( value );
    }
}
```

is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

So, do you want to get from the list all the object whose if is equal to an entry in the map?

....

```
List<Value> subset = ... 
for ( int id : map.keySet() ) {
   for ( Value v : list ) {
      if ( v.id() == id ) { 
           subset.add( v );
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is you will iterate the list one time for each key.

You can either solve this by having both the keys and the list ordered by id and something along the lines:

```
 int index = 0;
 for ( int id: map.keySet() ) {
     while ( index < list.size()  && list.get(index).id() == id ) {
        subset.add( list.get(index));
        index++;
     }
 }
```

Or (what I would do) is to remove the element from the list when found, that way the re-iteration will be a little less expansive.

```
for( int id : map.keySet() ) {
   for ( Iterator<Value> i  = list.iterator; i.hasNext(); ) {
      Value v = i.next();
      if ( v.id() == id ) {
          subset.add(v);
          i.remove();
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a full code of what you ask.

package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestMainClass
{

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Map<Integer, String> map = createDummyMap();

        final List<Value> list = createList();

        final List<Value> matchedValues = new ArrayList<TestMainClass.Value>();

        for (final Value value : list)
        {
            for (final Integer id : map.keySet())
            {
                if (id.equals(value.getId()))
                {
                    matchedValues.add(value);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(matchedValues.size());

    }

    private static List<Value> createList()
    {
        final Value value1 = new Value(1001, "some");
        final Value value2 = new Value(1002, "some");
        final Value value3 = new Value(1003, "some");
        final Value value4 = new Value(1004, "some");
        final Value value5 = new Value(1005, "some");

        return new ArrayList<TestMainClass.Value>(Arrays.asList(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, String> createDummyMap()
    {
        final Map<Integer, String> valueMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        valueMap.put(1001, "Test1");
        valueMap.put(1002, "Test2");
        valueMap.put(1003, "Test3");
        return valueMap;
    }

    public final static class Value
    {
        private int id;

        private String value;

        Value(final int id, final String value)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;

        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(final int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(final String value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Just consider that you iterate the keyset once for every item in the list.

Comment: IMHO, this is a bad solution because of your use of the nested for loop in combination with `equals()`. It's much more efficient to just loop over the values and use the `containsKey()` method on the map. (See my answer).